# Let ${a_{n + 1}} = \frac{{{a_n} - 1}}{{{a_n} + 1}}.$ How can we found general term of this sequence?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let

- $\left\{ {{a_n}} \right\}$ be a sequence.
- $\alpha \in \mathbb{R} .$
- $a_1=\alpha$
- ${a_{n + 1}} = \frac{{{a_n} - 1}}{{{a_n} + 1}}.$

How can we found general term of this sequence?

Comment: Have you tried starting from $n=0$, then $n=1$, etc, and writing out the expressions you obtain?

Comment: Is the second point to mean $\;a_0=\alpha\;$ ? (or $\;a_1\;$, it never matters)

Comment: @DonAntonio - I'm sorry. I edited this post.

Comment: Hint: compute $a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5$ by hand, what is $a_5$?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModularGroupGamma.html  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Möbius_transformation

Comment: @achillehui - What is $a_n$? Please more guide.

Comment: $a_2 = \frac{a_1 - 1}{a_1 + 1} = \frac{\alpha - 1}{\alpha+1}$, $a_3 = \frac{a_2-1}{a_2+1} = \frac{\frac{\alpha-1}{\alpha+1} - 1}{\frac{\alpha-1}{\alpha+1}+1}
= \frac{(\alpha-1)-(\alpha+1)}{(\alpha-1)+(\alpha+1)} = -\frac{1}{\alpha}$
Now if you compute $a_4$ and then $a_5$, you will find $a_5$...

Comment: @achillehui - Thanks, but what is $a_n$?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the person who asked is refusing to do anything at all. Just refusing. People are giving good advice, including suggestions for how to investigate and actually learn something through the experience

Comment: @Undersky Have you already done what achille hui proposed, and actually quite helped, you to do? It really is surprisingly easy...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume that $a_n=\frac{p_n}{q_n}$ is represented by the vector $v_n=(p_n,q_n)^T\in\mathbb{R}^2$. Then 
$$ a_{n+1} = \frac{p_n-q_n}{p_n+q_n} $$
is represented by the vector
$$ v_{n+1}=\begin{pmatrix}p_{n+1}\\ q_{n+1}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}v_n$$
so we may solve the problem by finding an explicit expression for $M^n$ where $M=\begin{pmatrix}1 & -1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}$.
Since the eigenvalues of $M$ are $1+i$ and $1-i$, by diagonalizing $M$ we get that
$$ p_n = A(1+i)^n + B(1-i)^n,\qquad q_n = C(1+i)^n+D(1-i)^n $$
for a set of constants $A,B,C,D$ that depend on $p_0,q_0,p_1,q_1$. By imposing $p_1=\alpha,q_1=1$, $p_2=\alpha-1$, $q_2=\alpha+1$ it is easy to find $A,B,C,D$, then the general expression for $a_n$:
$$ a_n = \color{red}{\frac{(1-i\alpha)+(\alpha-i)(-i)^n}{(1+i\alpha)(-i)^n-(\alpha+i)}}.$$
We may notice that since $M^4=-4I$, $\;\color{red}{a_n=a_{n+4}}$, so the whole sequence is made by the terms $\alpha,\frac{\alpha-1}{\alpha+1},-\frac{1}{\alpha}$ and $\frac{1+\alpha}{1-\alpha}$ only.